# Wordpress automatically replace space with underscore when update category name

Tags: wordpress

I've tackle something pretty weird in wordpress.
When I try to change category name, wordpress automatically replace space with under score, and also upper case with lower case, as if it was the slug.
The name should be "pretty", it needs to be present on the site, so this is a very strange behavior.

Note: it doesn't happen when I create new category, only when I change existing one.

Anyone now what's going on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question seems more suited for [wordpress.se] as it is about usage of WordPress, not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions for you:

- Are you using quick edit, or full edit?
- If you are using quick edit, have you tried the full edit?
- The theme you are using, is it a purchased theme?

It certainly is peculiar behaviour for Wordpress which makes me think it's related to either a plugin or the theme somehow.

> It does work in quick edit, thanks! – Avishay2

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Totally.. I tried adding a comment, but as you pointed out - not enough rep. 0_o